# An event with unclear purpose and data emitted in transactions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, transactions, polygon

I've observed this in multiple txs I've looked at, so, here's a random one on Polygon Mumbai: [**link**](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x053661fd00bf38c1e666dc02c727f51c188a1bb65618f190bb0098a354c5c8a9#eventlog).

It contains several emitted events, the last of which is this: [image]

1. What is this event and how to properly interpret its Topics and Data?
2. What does the "7" in the green circle to the left of the event details refer to?

Comment: The issue is that the smart contract is not verified. Polygonscan cannot infer the event name and arguments without the source code.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, excuse me, ser, but I tend to disagree. I've just reproduced this behavior on a verified test contract: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xe6Ef2a794340fa33633B13b367937bC7A4C5904E

Note that there's a successful and a failed tx immediately following the contract creation, but both of them contain the event similar (in content) to the one from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to **2)** is that "7" is the **id** of the respective event with regards to the whole block in which the tx has been included.

In the case above, the tx 0x053661fd00bf38c1e666dc02c727f51c188a1bb65618f190bb0098a354c5c8a9 was included second in block 32492205 which contained 2 txs in total. The first tx emitted 3 events that were assigned ids 0-2, while the current tx emitted 5 events that have got ids 3-7 respectively. The event from the original question was emitted last - and, therefore, has the id of "7" inside the block.